# Как получить значение из элементов коллекции List<Object>

Tags: java, циклы, arraylist

Исходные данные-результат запроса из базы данных в виде `List<Records>records`
В records содержатся 24 элемента(часы) в которых записаны записи для занесения данных в excel-файл.в классе `Records` просто список всех столбцов `public Double price,public Double cost` и т д; `records` имеет вид: `{0(price =5, cost=10),1(price =2, cost=8)` и т.д.} Вопрос как получить значения каждого элемента a в цикле?

```
for (Records a : records){
            for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
                excelTargets.add(new ExcelTarget(sheetName, row, columns[i],??));
            }
        row ++;
    }
```

Comment: приведите листинг класса Records и как список Records получается

Comment: если бы Вы добавили это в свой вопрос, и оформили должным образом, Вы быстрее бы получили ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте метод, который будет возвращать список Ваших полей. Например:

```
class TestRecord {
    int field1;
    int field2;
    int filed3;

    List<Object> getFields() {
        return Arrays.asList(field1, field2, filed3);
    }
}
```

Затем используйте его:

```
excelTargets.add(new ExcelTarget(sheetName, row, columns[i], a.getFields().get(i)));
```

Если Ваш класс Records нельзя отредактировать, можно расширить его функциональность с помощью наследования либо композиции.
Наследование:

```
class TestRecord {
    private int field1;
    private int field2;
    private int filed3;

    public int getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public int getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public int getFiled3() {
        return filed3;
    }
}

class MyTestRecord extends TestRecord {
    List<Object> getFields() {
        return Arrays.asList(getField1(), getField2(), getFiled3());
    }
}
```

Композиция:

```
TestRecord record = new TestRecord();
List<Object> fields = Arrays.asList(record.getField1(), record.getField2(), record.getFiled3());
excelTargets.add(new ExcelTarget(sheetName, row, columns[i], fields.get(i)));
```

Если все таки ни один из предложенных вариантов не подходит, можно использовать java reflection.

```
class TestRecord {
    private int field1 = 1;
    private int field2 = 2;
    private int filed3 = 3;
}

TestRecord record = new TestRecord();
List<Object> values = new ArrayList<>();
Field[] fields = TestRecord.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field field : fields) {
    field.setAccessible(true);
    values.add(field.get(record));
}
```

Comment: а без редактирования класса Record возможно решение? Я делаю запрос из др.класса

Comment: к сожалению ни один из способов не походит, объясню более подробно. У меня есть класс Records (с оч большим кол-вом записей), есть другой класс, в котором формируется запрос в который добавляются эти records. я же в своем классе,уже унаследованном, получаю  List<Records>records в виде {0(price =5, cost=10),1(price =2, cost=8)}

Comment: и мне нужно получить именно value каждого рекорда